# Computational Geometry set of points algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, points

I have to design an algorithm with running time O(nlogn) for the following problem:

Given a set P of n points, determine a value A > 0 such that the shear transformation (x,y) -> (x+Ay,y) does not change the order (in x direction) of points with unequal x-coordinates.

I am having a lot of difficulty even figuring out where to begin.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615964/shear-transformation-which-doesnt-change-the-order-in-x-direction

Answer (score 0):

I think y = 0.

```
When x = 0, A > 0
(x,y) -> (x+Ay,y)
      -> (0+(A*0),0) = (0,0)
When x = 1, A > 0
(x,y) -> (x+Ay,y)
      -> (1+(A*0),0) = (1,0)
```

with unequal x-coordinates, (2,0), (3,0), (4,0)...
So, I think that the begin point may be (0,0), x=0.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the problem - the idea is that you're given the (x, y) points and need to pick A.  You don't begin with x's and A and then need to pick y.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all x,y coordinates are positive numbers.  (Without loss of generality, one can add offsets.)  In time O(n log n), sort a list L of the points, primarily in ascending order by x coordinates and secondarily in ascending order by y coordinates.  In time O(n), process point pairs (in L order) as follows.  Let p, q be any two consecutive points in L, and let px, qx, py, qy denote their x and y coordinate values.  From there you just need to consider several cases and it should be obvious what to do:  If px=qx, do nothing.  Else, if py<=qy, do nothing.  Else (px>qx, py>qy) require that px + A*py < qx + A*qy, *i.e.* (px-qx)/(py-qy) > A.

So: Go through L in order, and find the largest A' that is satisfied for all point pairs where px>qx and py>qy.  Then choose a value of A that's a little less than A', for example, A'/2.  (Or, if the object of the problem is to find the largest such A, just report the A' value.)

Comment: This needs to be reviewed - if f(P) transforms (Pˣ, Pʸ) to (Pˣ + A*Pʸ, Pʸ) [with ˣ,ʸ denoting x,y components] and P, Q, R are 3 consecutive points in x coord, we could have f(P)ˣ < f(Q)ˣ but f(P)ˣ > f(R)ˣ, ie, just considering consecutive point pairs may fail.  Anyhow, pages 49&50 of a "presentations/2019 Camp 3/Computational Geometry (Andi Qu).pdf" document at https://saco-evaluator.org.za/ gives a more elegant method of solution, called "Convex Hull Trick" for linear functions of points

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a rough stab at a method.

Sort the list of points by x order.   (This gives the O(nlogn)--all the following steps are O(n).)

Generate a new list of dx_i = x_(i+1) - x_i, the differences between the x coordinates.   As the x_i are ordered, all of these dx_i >= 0.

Now for some A, the transformed dx_i(A) will be x_(i+1) -x_i + A * ( y_(i+1) - y_i).   There will be an order change if this is negative or zero (x_(i+1)(A) < x_i(A).

So for each dx_i, find the value of A that would make dx_i(A) zero, namely
A_i = - (x_(i+1) - x_i)/(y_(i+1) - y_i).  You now have a list of coefficients that would 'cause' an order swap between a consecutive (in x-order) pair of points.   Watch for division by zero, but that's the case where two points have the same y, these points will not change order.   Some of the A_i will be negative, discard these as you want A>0.  (Negative A_i will also induce an order swap, so the A>0 requirement is a little arbitrary.)

Find the smallest A_i > 0 in the list.   So any A with 0 < A < A_i(min) will be a shear that does not change the order of your points.   Pick A_i(min) as that will bring two points to the same x, but not past each other.